# Sequilize PostgreSQL query where array contains integer

Tags: node.js

I am trying to query all rows in a postgreSQL database that have an array `array` with data like `(1,2,3)` that contains a certain int say `2`. Using sequelize this is what I tried

```
where: {array: {$contains: [2]}}
and
where: {array: {$contains: 2}}
```

I end up getting this error:

`(node:30960) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: values.map is not a function`

EDIT

Solution:
`array: {[Op.contains]: [2]}`

Answer (score 0):

The argument passed to `$contains` (or `Op.contains`) should be an array.
For more details see [the manual](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/querying.html)